# Rails 3. Multiple values in one column using checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, authentication, checkbox

I followed this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association?view=comments which I think it's great but I want to handle the roles a bit differently.

I want to have a column 'roles' that stores comma delimited values, for example: "administrator, teacher" so that user has administrator and teacher roles assigned.

I would like to set that up having checkboxes.

What I currently have saves this instead: `"---\n- administrator\n- teacher\n- ''\n"`

How could I do that?

```
_form.html.erb
<div class="group">
  <%= f.label :roles, "Roles", :class => :label %>
  <% for role in User::ROLES %>
    <%= check_box_tag "user[roles][]", role, @user.roles.include?(role) %>
    <%=h role.humanize %><br />
  <% end %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "user[roles][]", "" %>
</div>

user.rb
ROLES = %w[superadmin admin instructor salesperson student]
```

Answer (score 2):

**view code**
Below should work

```
<% form_for @user do |f|%>
<div class="group">
  <%= f.label :roles, "Roles", :class => :label %>
  <% for role in User::ROLES %>
    <%= f.check_box :roles, :name => "#{f.object_name}[roles][]", role%>
    <%= h role.humanize %><br />
  <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

for more info [read](http://www.funonrails.com/2012/01/mongoid-array-field-and-rails-form.html) something similar